# Angularjs directive throws Unknown provider error after gulp minified js files

Tags: angularjs, directive

Thank you in advance!
I added custom directive to present field in phone number format. It works well untill gulp minifies the js files. After that it throws error
**[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- phoneInputDirective**
Is the special way to register the directive somewhere or so? I am not sure what is going on. Please help.

```
careApp.directive('phoneInput', function ($filter, $browser) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var listener = function () {
                var value = $element.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                $element.val($filter('tel')(value, false));
            };

            // This runs when we update the text field
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                return viewValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0, 10);
            });

            // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
            ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                $element.val($filter('tel')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, false));
            };

            $element.bind('change', listener);

            $element.bind('keydown', function (event) {
                var key = event.keyCode;
                // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
                // This lets us support copy and paste too
                if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)) {
                    return;
                }
                $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly
            });

            $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
                $browser.defer(listener);
            });
        }

    };
});

careApp.filter('tel', function () {
    return function (tel) {
        if (!tel) { return ''; }

        var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

        if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
            return tel;
        }

        var country, city, number;

        switch (value.length) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                city = value;
                break;

            default:
                city = value.slice(0, 3);
                number = value.slice(3);
        }

        if (number) {
            if (number.length > 3) {
                number = number.slice(0, 3) + '-' + number.slice(3, 7);
            }
            else {
                number = number;
            }

            return ("(" + city + ") " + number).trim();
        }
        else {
            return  city;
        }

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. The problem was dependence injection.
In the directive declaration the dependency should go before function in [] brackets.
In my case it was:
careApp.directive('phoneInput',['$filter', '$browser', function ($filter, $browser)
{....}
])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).